# Can a hamster be allergic to cats?

Tags: cats, allergies, hamsters

I live in an apartment with my Roborovski hamster, and my roommate has a cat. Occasionally the cat will get into my room and get close to him, and shortly after, I will notice him scratching himself a lot. Is it possible he might be allergic to it?

If this doesn't sound like the case, what does cause him to scratch so frequently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose it's *possible* that there's an allergy at play here but I'd be looking for a more likely cause first. Has the cat been checked/treated for fleas? Fleas, mites or ticks can transfer from cats to hamsters and that would certainly cause the scratching behavior you see.